# csv.Error: sequence expected

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to save JSON response for tone analysis from Watson API.

I just want to save the tone_name's values as headers and score values of each data to each row of CSV.

```
import csv

import json



infile=open('oobar.json', "rb")

json_s=infile.read()

outfile=open("watsf.csv","wb")

writer=csv.writer(outfile)

count = 0


for data in(json.loads(json_s)):
    categories = data['document_tone']
    for category in categories['tone_categories']:
        for tone in category['tones']:
            if count == 0:
                header = tone.values()[0]
                writer.writerow(header)
                count += 1
            writer.writerow(tone.values()[1])
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

i hoping to get a csv like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMjgo.jpg)

The response from Watson API is like this

```
[
  {
    "document_tone": {
      "tone_categories": [
        {
          "category_id": "emotion_tone",
          "tones": [
            {
              "tone_name": "Anger",
              "score": 0.068227,
              "tone_id": "anger"
            },
            {
              "tone_name": "Disgust",
              "score": 0.035456,
              "tone_id": "disgust"
            },
            {
              "tone_name": "Fear",
              "score": 0.043625,
              "tone_id": "fear"
            },
            {
              "tone_name": "Joy",
              "score": 0.779054,
              "tone_id": "joy"
            },
            {
              "tone_name": "Sadness",
              "score": 0.054364,
              "tone_id": "sadness"
            }
          ],
          "category_name": "Emotion Tone"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**EDIT**

`writer.writerow`was throwing `Error: sequence expected` error.

Comment: Try `writer.writerow([tone.values()[1]])`. `writerow` expects a sequence (a list is one sequence)

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the JSON you provided (a curly brace is missing).

So I was able to fix your code, although I'm not sure if this is the solution you expected.

By adding `writer.writerow([tone.values()[1]])` instead of `writer.writerow([tone.values()[1]])` (not the brackets). Each row will have only one item. It results in the following csv output:

```
A,n,g,e,r
0.068227
0.035456
0.043625
0.779054
0.054364
```

Let me know if this is the format you were looking for.

Basically, `writerow` expects a list of values [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow).

You may want to consider using `with` blocks instead of manually opening and closing the files. You can also open multiple files in the same block:

```
with open('oobar.json', "rb") as infile, open("watsf.csv","wb") as outfile:
    json_s=infile.read()

    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
```

It's a best practice since you're not risking to leave the files open by mistake.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, The goal is to get the 5 different emotions as column names and corresponding values in each row. I added a image in the question for reference.